# Call function in child component if condition is true

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to call a function in a child component only if certain variable is true. Otherwise do nothing

```
allowDeleteItem = false;

<ChildComponent
....
removeItemFn={ deleteFn } />
```

I tried to add my boolean varible inside curly braces and do a condition like `{ allowDeleteItem && deleteFn }` but I have a typescript error which I am difficulty to solve this.

An alternative is to pass the boolean variable as a prop to the child component and there make the validation. This case I can solve it but I was looking a possible "cleaner" way

Answer (score 1):

My guess is the error you may have received is because you tried to conditionally send the function reference to the child prop, maybe like this `removeItemFn={allowDeleteItem && deleteFn}`? This is potentially problematic because if the condition is not met, you are sending a value of 'undefined' which can break logic that may rely on that value in the child prop.

I don't know enough about your project so I'll list one possibility:

You could opt to use the [React Context API.](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). If the `deleteFn` function and `allowDeleteItem` boolean are being passed down from the parent component to many child components, you can avoid passing them as props for each component by creating a context and setting each child component as a Context Consumer. The Parent will act as a Context Provider. This way in the child components you can just call the useContext() hook to get access to those values.

Otherwise, it will just be easier to send the `allowDeleteItem` boolean as another prop. Even though it may not seem clean at first, later on you might see that it is the simplest  way or that there is another way to condense your code. In my experience, it is always better to get the functionality working first then cleaning up the code after.

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try something like this:

```
allowDeleteItem = false;

<ChildComponent
....
removeItemFn={ allowDeleteItem?deleteFn:undefined } />
```

and inside ChildComponent make your deleteFn optional parameter like below:

```
interface ChildComponentProps{
....other props
deleteFn?:Function or whatever way you are using it
}
```